# Isolate objects in only one viewport

Tags: objects, 3d-view

I split the screen to Render viewport and Solid viewport. I want to isolate the object only in Solid viewport and want the Render viewport shows all objects. However, whenever I isolate in Solid viewport, the Render one also shows that object only. How can I only isolate in one viewport and not affect the other one?[image: the problem][image: what i want to achieve]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Have you tried pressing numpad `/` forward slash?

Comment: You're not in isolated view, looks to me like you've hidden all objects except the one you're viewing. This will cause them to be hidden in all viewports. Use "local view" (`/`)
What are you pressing to "isolate in Solid viewport"?